# How to find average in an array after entered into a text box, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random, average

*My code so far:*
**How do I get the average of the random array along with already max and min?**

```
function displayResults() {  
  var textDisplay2 = "";  
  for (var i in scores) {  
      var max = Math.max.apply(null, scores);  
      var n = max.toString();  
      var count = scores.indexOf(n);  
      var min = Math.min.apply(null, scores);  
      var textDisplay = "";  
      for (var i in names) {  
          textDisplay += names[i] + "," + scores[i] + "\n";  
      }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code so we can have an example we can run.

Comment: This code does not compile!

Answer (score 0):

If I get your thoughts right you like to calculate the average if an array *(in this case max and min is not important)*:

You can calculate the average of an array using this line:

```
var average = (yourArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; })) / yourArray.length;
```

---

This line is calculating the sum of all array elements:

```
var sum = (yourArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }))
```

and dividing the sum trough the elements count  will give you the **average**!

```
var avg = sum / yourArray.length
```

---

Here you go! `:)`